# Calling javascript in codebehind

Tags: c#, javascript, c, telerik

I am calling javascript via codebehind. Giving object expected error. How can I pass some value through ShowDialog() function?

here is my code in codebehind

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Call my function", "ShowDialog("Value_here");", true);
```

and in my javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var IRProjectID = 0;

    function ShowDialog(UnitID) {
        radconfirm("Are you sure you want to approve this Help Desk item?", confirmBackChecked);
        IRProjectID = UnitID;
    }

    function confirmBackChecked(arg) {
        if (arg == true) {
            __doPostBack(IRProjectID, 'Approve');
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Call My Function", "ShowDialog("Value_here");", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Test", "ShowDialog("+Value_here+");", true);
```

Comment: can u tell me where r u getting the error exactly.Is it a run time error or compile error.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your calling a javascript function too soon... Try with `Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock`

Be carefull when you call javascript function. Be sure that it exist before!!!.

**Edit**:

`Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock` is obsolete, use `ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock`

Comment: `Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock` is obsolete.

Comment: ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock

Comment: ¿Do you have a ScriptManager on your page?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is thrown by the double quotes you use around Value_here

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Call my function", "ShowDialog("Value_here");", true);
```

try this

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Call my function", "ShowDialog(\"Value_here\");", true);
```

or

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Call my function", "ShowDialog('Value_here');", true);
```